# Find group of elements by first half of the id attribute?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a series of elements like:

```
<input id="box-2585">
<input id="box-2586">
```

How can I select all elements like `$('#box-')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector `^=`

```
$('[id^="box-"]')
```

This will get all elements with an attribute of id **starting** with `box-`

```js
console.log($('[id^="box-"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box-2585">
<input id="box-2586">
```